# Why the value changes on macro assignment to a variable?

Tags: system-verilog

Here in the below code . `` `append(MANGO); `` returns 25. where as `` val = `append(MANGO); `` value getting stored in val is 53 .Why is it happening like that?

```
`define T_APPLE_FRUIT 13
`define T_MANGO_FRUIT 25

`define append(MOD) `"`T_``MOD``_FRUIT`"

module test;
  bit[7:0] val;

  initial begin
    $display(`append(MANGO));

    $display ("\n\n%d\n",val);
    val = `T_MANGO_FRUIT;

    $display ("%d\n",val);
    val = `append(MANGO);

    $display ("\n%d\n",val);
  end
endmodule
```

```
run -all;
 KERNEL: 25
 KERNEL: 
 KERNEL: 
 KERNEL:   0
 KERNEL: 
 KERNEL:  25
 KERNEL: 
 KERNEL: 
 KERNEL:  53
 KERNEL: 
 KERNEL: Simulation has finished. There are no more test vectors to simulate.
```

Answer (score 1):

1. the first $display gets the quoted string as an argument, as it is defined in your macro. It is supposed to display this string, nothing else. No idea why your compiler does wrong job there and displays a number.
2. you define 'val' as `bit[7:0]`. This makes `val` a 2-state variable with initial value of `0`. Therefore your first $display is supposed to print `0`'
3. you assign value of  the `T_MANGO_FRUIT` macro to the `val`, which is 25 and is displayed as such
4. you assign an array of characters as a double-quoted string ("T_MANGO_FRUIT") to `val`. Again, not sure why you are getting 53 there, it is supposed to be 84, which is an ascii code of the first char `T`. Which compiler did you use?

My guess is that you wanted to define `append` as this:

```
`define append(MOD) `T_``MOD``_FRUIT
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for having a look at the code. Once i specify the base specifiers and changed to `` `define append(MOD) `T_``MOD``_FRUIT `` . Its working fine.